# ¿Se pueden crear excepciones a una estructura de control selectiva (If-Else)?

Tags: java, poo

Mi problema es en un algoritmo de números primos. La lógica que utilicé en Java fue la siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);


    System.out.print("Su rango de numeros primos es del 1 hasta: ");
    int ultimoNumero = entrada.nextInt();
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------\n\n");

    System.out.println("INICIO\n\n");

    int vNumero;
    System.out.println("2\n3\n5\n7");
    for (vNumero = 2; vNumero<=ultimoNumero; vNumero++){

        if (vNumero%1==0 & vNumero%2!=0 & vNumero%3!=0 & vNumero%4!=0 & vNumero%5!=0 & vNumero%6!=0 & vNumero%7!=0 
            & vNumero%8!=0 & vNumero%9!=0 & vNumero%vNumero==0){

            System.out.println(vNumero);

        }     
}

    System.out.println("FIN");
```

Sé que no es una buena manera para hacer dicho algoritmo, puesto que no me imprimiría el 2,3,5 y 7. Por eso me llegó pregunta a la cabeza. ¿Se pueden hacer excepciones a la condición inicial?

Comment: Sí , Una `Exception` con un mensaje definido ?

Comment: Esas excepciones las puedes hacer con break y continue, y tambien con un throw y con  throw new, pero eso logica no es la adecuada cuando ya existen algoritmos que lo hacen https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criba_de_Atkin

Comment: @Dev.Joel me parece que el OP se refiere a hacer una excepción a una validación en el `if`

Comment: Creo que tu problema está en plantear un mejor algoritmo para determinar si un número es primo.

Comment: Eso lo tengo claro, no es la lógica adecuada, puesto que soy novato y lo hice de mis conocimiento matemáticos. Debo mejorar el algoritmo, pero quería saber si podía establecer la excepción de que los números 2, 3, 5 y 7 se imprimieran sin importar la condición establecida en el If-Else. Es decir, que se impriman importando únicamente el rango establecido por el usuario. Ejemplo si el usuario quiere los primos desde el 1 hasta el 5, se impriman solo el 2,3 y 5, siendo estos una excepción a la condición. Quiero saber si es posible. Ya uno respondió como seria posible, debo de probar lo que dijo.

Comment: Te recomiendo consultar los operadores lógicos de Java, creo que intentas usar el "y" lógico, por ejemplo quiero algo bonito y barato, el operador que buscar es &&(estas usando & que significa otra cosa), además pues aprender del operador "o" (||) para excepciones y el not para negar (!) te serán muy útiles.